# npm login --always-auth doesn't add the appropriate entry to the config

Tags: authentication, npm, npm-install, artifactory

I use npm version 6.13.7 and Artifactory repository manager. The registry URL is defined in `.npmrc` in my project folder:

```
root@2892c246217b:/build# cat .npmrc
registry=https://<masked>/artifactory/api/npm/<masked>
```

I want to use an authentication token created via `npm login` command:

```
root@2892c246217b:/build# npm login --always-auth
Username: <masked>
Password:
Email: (this IS public) <masked>
Logged in as <masked> on https://<masked>/artifactory/api/npm/<masked>.
```

Now an install should work, however it doesn't:

```
root@2892c246217b:/build# npm install
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-02-04T17_28_52_957Z-debug.log
```

I check `/root/.npmrc/` and see that `always-auth` entry is missing. So I add it via `npm config`:

```
root@2892c246217b:/build# npm config set always-auth true
```

And fetching works fine:

```
root@2892c246217b:/build# npm --verbose install
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'install' ]
npm info using npm@6.13.7
npm info using node@v10.18.0
npm verb npm-session fd8f804800679bcc
npm info lifecycle <masked>@2.0.0~preinstall: <masked>@2.0.0
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 10ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 4ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://<masked>/artifactory/api/npm/<masked>/<masked> 109ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://<masked>/artifactory/api/npm/<masked>/<masked> 149ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://<masked>/artifactory/api/npm/<masked>/<masked>/-/<masked>.tgz 46ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://<masked>/artifactory/api/npm/<masked>/<masked> 309ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://<masked>/artifactory/api/npm/<masked>/<masked> 738ms
...
```

Is that a bug in `npm` or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: It's a bug in npm: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/704 I also had to add it manually with `npm config`

Comment: @JCE thanks, i've subscribed to this issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems that "always-auth" is not needed at all when using "npm login" command, but only if you use basic authentication.

My .npmrc looks like: (using npm login command)

```
registry=http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/
//localhost:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/:_authToken=<TOKEN_MASKED>
```

Also, from Artifactory's "Set Me Up" page, it does not seem necessary, only if you use basic authentication:

[image]

Comment: But if `always-auth` is not the culprit, why else `npm install` doesn't work after `npm login`?

Comment: @DannyLo I tried to reproduce the behavior you encountered, but in my case, it worked without "always-auth". 

Try to delete your current .npmrc (make sure you back it up first) and try the following steps: 

1. npm config set registry <ARTIFACTORY_URL:PORT/artifactory/api/npm/NPM_REPOSITORY_NAME>

2. npm login 
* Please try to use it without the "always-auth"

Comment: My ~/.npmrc file looks yours now: `registry=...` in the first line and `//https://<masked>/artifactory/api/npm/<masked>:_authToken=<MASKED>` in the second. I still get error code 401